# What Is Difference Between Json and Jsonp?

Tags: json, jsonp

I am trying to access cross origin site via script.

So I am getting an error, I have searched on internet that shows the solution is the `JsonP`.

Anyone Please help me to know what is jsonp  .

and what is the difference between **json and jsonp**.

Is JSONP cross browser compatible?
can i use jsonp in mobile applications or asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

JSONP is a simple way to overcome browser restrictions when sending JSON responses from different domains from the client.

But the practical implementation of the approach involves subtle differences that are often not explained clearly.

Here is a simple tutorial that shows JSON and JSONP side by side.

All the code is freely available at Github and a live version can be found at [http://json-jsonp-tutorial.craic.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20160114013014/http://json-jsonp-tutorial.craic.com/index.html)

Comment: as of April 2017, the link to json-jsonp-tutorial is down.

Comment: @faridcs http://json-jsonp-tutorial.craic.com/ is not working :(

Comment: Replaced dead link to JSON tutorial with Web Archive version